# object mapping for [doc.awsRegion] tried to parse field [awsRegion] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-dynamodb

I am using [Logstash Dynamodb PLugin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLogstash.html) to index data to be able to query it. Everything was running pretty smoothly, until one of my teammates started messing with the schema, and broke it. We can still index the data fine, however new data no longer comes in real time.

I see the following in Logstash log when it get stuck:

> :response=>{"index"=>{"_inde                                                                           x"=>"logstash-2016.04.27", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"00f523811be58f248a7aba6d07a5e6cc67a6c23591369b5ef711f91a481b1213", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapp                                                                                er_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"object mapping for [doc.awsRegion] tried to parse field [awsRegion] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}, :level=>:war                                                                                n}

How can I remove static mappings or change the parsing of that field to default?

Already tried removing the index and the ES data folder with no avail.